# Query data from firebase realtime database in cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is my image of firebase realtime database

[image]

I want to query just all usernames from the database as we do in SQL like we query a single column from database table:

```
"Select usernames from TABLE"
```

I want the same query in node JS. I am using cloud functions.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked. Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you're new to NoSQL, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), specifically the [video on common queries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&t=1s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&index=4).

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: not that much difficult .simple use query on child  or on  parent query.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime Database is not a SQL database. It is a object-based NoSQL type of database. So you can not use a query language, that is designed for queries against a table based relational database.

But there is a firebase-admin sdk for NodeJS:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start